# Is there a way to run a GCP Cloud Function locally while authenticated as a service account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I'm fairly new to GCP Cloud Functions.

I'm developing a cloud function within a GCP project which needs to access some other resources from the project (such as GCS, for instance). When I set up a cloud function, it gets a service account associated to it, so, I'm able give this service account the required permissions on the IAM and it works just fine in production.

I'm handling the required integrations by using the GCP SDKs and identifying the resources relative to the GCP project. For instance, if I need to access a GCS bucket within that project, it looks something like this:

```
    const bucket = await storage.bucket("bucket-name");
```

The problem with this is that I'm not able to access these resources if I'm running the cloud function locally for development, so, I have to deploy it every time to test it, which is a process that takes some time and makes development fairly unproductive.

So, is there any way I can run this cloud function locally whilst keeping the access to the necessary project resources so that I'm able to test it while developing? I figured that running this function as it's service account could work, but I don't know how to do it and I'm also open to different approaches.

Comment: If your user account as access to the account, authenticate yourself on your computer with the command `gcloud auth application-default login`. The client libraries use ADC to detect that authentication (as it detects that you run on Google Cloud) and reuse your credentials to run your code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is!

The only thing you need to do is setting the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to the path of a service account json file and then the googleapis libraries handle the rest automatically, most of the time.